# Jenkins shared library writeFile pom.xml

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

Why i can't do this with pom.xml file?
Always get error: No such library resource my_pom.xml could be found.

```
def call() {
  
  def mvnPomXml = libraryResource encoding: 'UTF-8', resource: 'my_pom.xml'
  writeFile file: 'pom.xml', text: mvnPomXml
  }
```

Comment: It is impossible to help without more information... Could you provide more information?